# jQuery slideToggle - callback function on slideUp action only

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know a good way to fire a callback function on the slideUp event only during a slideToggle? The default callback function fires on both slideUp and slideDown.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can check if the element [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) [`:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) since it'll be hidden at the end of a slide up, like this:

```
$(this).slideToggle(function() {
  if($(this).is(":hidden")) {
    alert("this was a slide up");
  }
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/pjMXp/).

Comment: Thanks Nick! Worked like a charm.

Comment: What am I missing? Your example reports a slide-up either way. Maybe I don't understand the question.

Comment: @Robusto - that shoudn't be the case, which browser are you in?

Comment: I just tested in Firefox 3.6.12